# Trying to initialize a char array in a struct but I'm missing something

Tags: c

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char    private_key[ PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE ];
    char    certificate[ CERTIFICATE_SIZE ];
    uint8_t cooee_key  [ COOEE_KEY_SIZE ];
} platform_dct_security_t;
```

In my main function, I declared my variable:

```
platform_dct_security_t* dct_security = NULL;
```

Now I need to fill the arrays in this struct.

I also have my certificate defined like this:

```
#define CERTIFICATE_STRING  \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"\
"MIIFIzCCBAugAwIBAgIETB0zITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBsTELMAkGA1UE\r\n"\

                        ...
                        ...

"uhZ2VrLWSJLyi6Y+t6xcaeoLP2ZFuQ==\r\n"\
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"\
"\0"\
"\0"
```

So I proceeded:

```
memcpy( dct_security->certificate, CERTIFICATE_STRING, CERTIFICATE_SIZE );
printf( "\n%s\n", dct_security->certificate );
```

However, this prints out something garbage. I also tried this but it didn't work either:

```
(*dct_security) = { CERTIFICATE_STRING, PRIVATE_KEY_STRING, COOEE_KEY_STRING };
```

When I compile and run with this, it doesn't crash but it gets stuck and nothing is printed out.

If I define another `char` array without having a `struct`, it works like a charm:

```
char xyz[ CERTIFICATE_SIZE ];
memcpy( xyz, CERTIFICATE_STRING, CERTIFICATE_SIZE );
printf("\n%s\n", xyz);
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: You do make the pointer variable `dct_security` actually point somewhere valid? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg means is: Did you allocated any memory for the pointer(e.g. with `malloc`) or initialized it somewhere else?

Comment: `dct_security` is not a variable of type `platform_dct_security_t`! Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JoachimPileborg @ckruczek Thank you very much, it appears that's what I was missing. Instead of initializing it with `NULL`, I used `malloc()` and it now works. I'm not sure if I got the logic behind this, though.

Comment: @Motun It seems you might need to pick up [a beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and revisit the chapters on pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) and [ckruczek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4849573/ckruczek) made me realize, I needed to allocate some memory for `dct_security`. So this change fixed the problem:

```
platform_dct_security_t* dct_security;
dct_security = malloc(sizeof(platform_dct_security_t));
```

Comment: don't cast the result of `malloc`. also you should not use the `(char *)` cast in the other part of your code. Try to avoid using casts unless there is no alternative.